# Setting up eth0 interface from /boot in Raspbian Stretch

Tags: networking, ethernet, pi-zero

#### Background / Setup:

- OS - Raspbian Stretch lite
- Board - Raspberry Pi Zero (no WiFi / no Ethernet)
- Ethernet Adapter - USB to Ethernet adapter

#### The way I have got it working:

- After writing the Raspbian image to a SD card, I create an empty file "ssh" in \boot (from windows) in order to enable sshd at boot
- Startup the Raspberry Pi using the new SD card and Ethernet adapter plugged in
- I run nmap from another Linux box to scan open ssh ports on devices on my network and find IP of the new system
- log into new system
- edit /etc/network/interfaces file (below)

> ```
> source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
>
> allow-hotplug eth0
> auto eth0
> iface eth0 inet static
>     address 192.168.25.27
>     netmask 255.255.255.0
>     gateway 192.168.25.4
>     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
>     hwaddress 00:e0:4c:53:44:27
> ```

- Reboot and ssh into the specified IP

Using the setup above, all works fine. I don't want to use DHCP.

#### Question:

I would like to know if there is some way to configure my USB Ethernet adapter from /boot (FAT partition) --> ***before booting*** <-- and logging into the system. I have tried to use ip=xx.xx.xx.xx in cmdline.txt but it doesn't work for me. I also have to setup a MAC address for my Ethernet adapter.

Comment: Can't you use the serial console?

Comment: yes I used the serial console using the physical pins. but I don't want to going forward if there is a way to do it without soldering header pins.

Comment: You don't need to solder any pins, just three jumper wires and one USB<->Serial Module (aka FTDI Breakout).

Comment: If you have access to your router, set the static IP using MAC address mapping from the router instead of from RPi.

Comment: I have emphasized on "before booting" in my question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways.

1. Serial console

Connect Tx/Rx and GND pins to your Pi's serial console pin and your USB<->UART board. Make sure your USB<->UART module uses 3V3 logic level to prevent damage to the Pi.

2. USB Gadget Ethernet

As you mentioned you are using RPi Zero, one of the two USB ports obviously work as power, but the another one work as an OTG, which means your Pi Zero can be a USB host (connecting mouse to it, etc), or a USB device (emulating as an ethernet adapter) using the same port. You can add `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` to your `cmdline.txt`, then connect the Pi to your computer through a micro USB cable. Your Pi Zero will now act as an ethernet device, you can connect to it via SSH at `raspberrypi.local` and perform your required configurations. If your Pi Zero need access to the internet, you can even enable Internet Connection Sharing (Windows), PC Sharing Connections (Ubuntu), etc.

3. Directly edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` on a Linux machine

This is the most straightforward way, just mount the raspbian partition on your Linux machine and modify your required files.

Comment: My question is about how to add Ethernet parameters using /boot

Comment: Why it has to be modifying `/boot`? What's wrong with the suggested solution to try to solve your issue? Can you provide the model name and the kernel module name for the USB <-> Ethernet adapter?

Comment: Chun, I wish to setup eth0 before boot. As stated in my question, I already have a way to setup eth0 *AFTER* boot, my quest is here to setup eth0 *BEFORE* boot. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: I have emphasized on "before booting" in my question

Comment: Your answer unfortunately doesn't answer my question as I want to configure eth0 before powering on my Pi. I hope you get it.

Comment: Sure, I understand you want to configure eth0 *before* your first boot (though I am unsure why), can you provide the driver (/kernel module) name of your USB to Ethernet Adapter? Btw, solution 3 does doesn't require to boot the RPi before configuration.

Comment: @ Kong Chun Ho the reason I want to configure my interface is that I want my interface ready for ssh login when I first boot. It is just a convenience factor. I can always reconfigure it after boot as I have stated in my question

Comment: *Solution 3* can be as convenience as modifying `/boot` provided that you are using a Linux machine. I am still waiting for your input on the name of the kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access of your router, you can set up static IP from your router instead of from RPi. All you need is the MAC address of the USB Ethernet port.

Comment: I need to hard code my MAC as well

Comment: I have emphasized on "before booting" in my question

Comment: The USB ethernet adapter that I have has a generic MAC address, therefore I need to explicitly set my own MAC before boot. Any pointers?